# Sección de dos columnas (imagen y texto) donde la imagen sobresalga del ancho máximo del contenedor

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando maquetar esta estructura donde la imagen **sobresale** del contenedor a la izquierda, como si fuera un elemento "full width", mientras que la columna del párrafo respeta el max-width que le he dado al elemento contenedor padre.

> Lo que busco es que el párrafo que está al lado de la imagen no se salga de la grilla delimitada por las líneas azules, como el primer párrafo, pero que la imagen sí que sobresalga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura HTML sería tal que así:

```
<div class="contenido">
    <div class="contenedor-max">

        <p>Párrafo 1</p>

        <div class="seccion">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/"/>
            <p>Párrafo de ejemplo</p>   
        </div>

        <div class="seccion">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/"/>
            <p>Párrafo de ejemplo</p>   
        </div>

        <p>Párrafo 2</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Y el CSS:

```
.contenido {
    width: 100%;
}    

.contenedor-max {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1100px;
 }

 .seccion {
        align-items: center
        display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edición**

> Quite la idea de *CSS Grid* y traté de lograrlo con *FlexBox*

Estuve probando algunos cambios para tratar de igualar la maquetación que buscas y lo que se me ocurrió fue lo siguiente:

- Un contenedor principal que envolverá:

  - Dos divs que servirán de columnas
  - una etiqueta `p` que nos servirá para tener los párrafos
  - un div después del párrafo que envuelve a una etiqueta `img` para lograr tener un contenido que se salga del contenedor principal
- Al contenedor principal dale estas propiedades:

  - Un ancho máximo del `95%`
  - Centralo con `margin: 0 auto;`
  - Aplicale `display: flex;` *esto para que ambos `div`* se acomoden uno a lado del otro y generen las *columnas*
- A los `div` que contienen las imágenes aplicales un ancho máximo del `100%` para que se ajuste a su contenedor y la imagen no rompa la estructura
- Para sacar a las imágenes de su contenedor puedes hacer uso de `margin` e indicando en porcentaje o pixeles cuanto lo vas a mover

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body{
          margin: 0;
        }
        .contenedor-principal {
          display: flex;
          max-width: 95%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .contenedor-principal__izquierda,
        .contenedor-principal__derecha {
          background: tomato;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .contenedor-principal__izquierda {
          border-right: 1px solid white;
        }
        .contenedor-principal__imagen-izquierda img{
          margin-left: -20%;
          max-width: 100%;
        }
        .contenedor-principal__imagen-derecha img{
          margin-left: 20%;
          max-width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="contenedor-principal">
      <div class="contenedor-principal__izquierda">
        <p class="contenedor-principal__parrafo">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, quasi, odit. Harum nihil similique deleniti itaque dolor eaque dolores alias beatae commodi repellat. Deleniti perferendis ad quisquam aliquid iure quas!
        </p>
        <div class="contenedor-principal__imagen-izquierda">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
        <p class="contenedor-principal__parrafo">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, quasi, odit. Harum nihil similique deleniti itaque dolor eaque dolores alias beatae commodi repellat. Deleniti perferendis ad quisquam aliquid iure quas!
        </p>
        <div class="contenedor-principal__imagen-izquierda">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor-principal__derecha">
        <p class="contenedor-principal__parrafo">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, quasi, odit. Harum nihil similique deleniti itaque dolor eaque dolores alias beatae commodi repellat. Deleniti perferendis ad quisquam aliquid iure quas!
        </p>
        <div class="contenedor-principal__imagen-derecha">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="">      
        </div>
        <p class="contenedor-principal__parrafo">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque aspernatur consequatur molestiae! Itaque, commodi, ab nemo sint accusamus ut unde officiis, praesentium, officia a vero delectus blanditiis laudantium nesciunt doloremque!
        </p>
        <div class="contenedor-principal__imagen-derecha">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="">      
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hola! La respuesta que has dado es exactamente lo que estaba haciendo con flex, pero eliminando el contenedor con max-width, pero eso no es lo que busco.

Lo que busco es que el párrafo que está al lado de la imagen no se salga de la grilla delimitada por las líneas azules, como el primer párrafo, pero que la imagen sí que sobresalga.

Un saludo!

Comment: @Pablo deja ver qué puedo hacer

Comment: @Pablo espero la edición te sea de ayuda